# Ember.js - "Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM" caused by template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've been having an issue with Ember.js throwing the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726460/cannot-perform-operations-on-a-metamorph-that-is-not-in-the-dom-in-ie8-on) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676663/ember-js-cannot-perform-operations-on-a-metamorph-that-is-not-in-the-dom) SO questions, both of which involve direct manipulation of the DOM, which is not the case in my app. Searching for the error message also returns numerous Github issues related to the same type of direct DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was at a loss until I happened upon [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1580) on Github from a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=handlebars+comments&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS521US521&oq=handlebars+comments&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.3252j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=handlebars+comments&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS521US521&oq=handlebars+comments&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.3252j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&pws=0&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg&fp=551399612b7414dc&biw=1304&bih=707) entirely unrelated with the error message.

Basically, the error boils down to a Handlebars expression enclosed within an HTML comment.

It's probably easier said in code than in words, so here's a jsFiddle with lots of explanation baked in: http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/JSj7W/1/

The `{{computedProp}}` expression is used three places within the template: as normal, within an HTML comment, and within a Handlebars block comment. Open up the web inspector and click the "Recompute" button to see the error produced.

You can remove the HTML comment from the example's template, and see that the code will run just fine when it is not present.

Hopefully, this will guide other blossoming Ember developers to such a simple solution more readily.

Comment: Nice catch. Thinking it might make sense to add a note about this to the ember error message.

Comment: That jsfiddle is an excellent example of a reproducible case. However, it does not cover all cases, as I am now dealing with a case of my own that has nothing to do with html comments.

Comment: Did you find what those other cases were?

Comment: Wow,  thank you for posting this answer.  Just saved me from probably spending an hour pulling my hair out.

Comment: I'd like to add that I got this same error when I used a Handlebars `{{#each}}` inside a `<tbody>` tag.  It seems that Handlebars doesn't handle these situations well. https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/604

Comment: @MiguelMadero's comment below solved my case. I was using:

`<div class="scroll-content has-header {{#if showFooter}} has-footer{{/if}}">`

instead of:

`<div class="scroll-content has-header {{bind-attr has-footer=showFooter}}">`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is simple, but tracking the actual cause is hard. For items that we track using metamorph, it wraps beteween a script element with an id of `metamorph-##-start` and id `metamorph-##-end`. Under normal circumstances, Ember shouldn't remove them unless they're no longer needed. There're a couple of reasons why this could be removed:

- Manually manipulating the DOM. If you manually remove the script tags, then, well they won't be found.
- Malformed HTML. Let's say you left an open div, then the metamorph-##-end tag will get nested at a different level than the start tag.

Comment: It was the 2nd case for me: I had the following malformed HTML on the last line of my .hbs file: </section

Adding the missing > and it worked again..

Comment: another example of how it could happen, calling:
`$('#your_div_with_handlebars_exprs').html('overwriting');`

Answer (score 4):

Another cause are the attributes in HTML tags when we using handlebars data, for example:

```
<div data-id="{{ model.id }}" ...
```

Use [`binding element attributes`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/) instead of normal method, for example:

```
<div {{ bind-attr data-id=model.id }} ...
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this insight! It saved me a ton of research and googling!